Jackson swallows empty JSON object upon parsing in Vertx
The code in Vert.x-Web "controller" of vertxVersion=4.5.11
var mapper = DatabindCodec.mapper();
mapper.configure( SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false );
mapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false );
mapper.setSerializationInclusion( Include.NON_EMPTY );

...

router.patch( "/my" ).consumes( JSON ).produces( JSON ).blockingHandler( this::validate );

...

void validate( RoutingContext rc ) {
  JsonObject json = rc.body().asJsonObject();
  log.info( "validate {} >> {}", rc.body().asString(), json );
}

upon receiving a JSON request of:
{
    "object": {
        "name": "aaa",
        "data": {
            "weNr": []
        }
    }
}

the "data" field is being ignored, producing the following log:
validate {"object":{"name":"aaa","data":{"weNr":[]}}} >> {"object":{"name":"aaa"}}}

If the weNr Array is filled, the parsed JSON looks as expected:
validate {"object":{"name":"aaa","data":{"weNr":[9410]}}} >> {"object":{"name":"aaa","data":{"weNr":[9410]}}

If the "data" has some other not-empty field, it's preserved but the empty "weNr" gets still swallowed:
{
    "object": {
        "name": "aaa",
        "data": {
            "weNr": [],
            "boo":"far"
        }
    }
}

produces:
validate {"object":{"name":"aaa","data":{"weNr":[],"boo":"far"}}} >> {"object":{"name":"aaa","data":{"boo":"far"}}}}

How can I configure DatabindCodec.mapper() or DatabindCodec.mapper().getFactory() or something else, to allow for empty JSON objects?

That's the behavior I would expect from the Include.NON_EMPTY directive (although I cannot reproduce it here). What happens if you change it to Include.ALWAYS?

@forty-two Don't think it's going to make a difference based on 2 simple facts: my problem appears even before the deserialization.

Well, JsonObject -> String feels a lot like serialization. But I might be wrong.

the problem is, that the parts get missing before converting JSON to POJO -> during parsing phase

Did you inspect what's really in the JsonObject as read from the body?

see the code and log outputs it produces

It turns out, that mapper.setSerializationInclusion( NON_EMPTY ) has an influence not only on serialization of POJOs, but also - against any logic - on JSON parsing.
As soon I replaced the NON_EMPTY with NON_NULL, the parsing and deserialization started working as expected.
Needless to say, that Javadoc does NOT highlight this...
